# Search Range in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python

I have implemented this algorithm, but I would like to get ride of the variable `res`, which is outside the `Solution` `class`, could anyone help me with this?

```
"""
Definition of TreeNode:
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left, self.right = None, None
"""
res = []
class Solution:
    """
    @param root: The root of the binary search tree.
    @param k1 and k2: range k1 to k2.
    @return: Return all keys that k1<=key<=k2 in ascending order.
    """     
    def searchRange(self, root, k1, k2):
        # write your code here
        if root is None:
            return []
        if root.val > k1:
            self.searchRange(root.left, k1, k2)
        if root.val >= k1 and root.val <= k2:
            res.append(root.val)
        if root.val < k2:
            self.searchRange(root.right, k1, k2)
        return res
```

Comment: Why does "res" need to be global and not local to searchRange?

Comment: And more importantly, why, oh why does that function have to go inside a class?

Comment: I have resolved it, moving the res into class, making it a class variable, and modify res into self.res.

Comment: @Jaime the reason of why the function is inside a class, is that it's a question of leetcode, which they have to form the question like this, so it's easy to run the test cases.

Comment: Why has this been down voted so badly? Looks like a good question to me. OP knows that Globals Are Bad (tm), but doesn't know how to rid the code of one and has asked us to help them improve their code. Looks on topic to me.

Answer (score 5):

- You should change `searchRange` to `search_range` as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's style guide.
- If this is Python2 then you should use `Solution(object)`. (This is why we have version tags).
- `res` should go *in* the function. As per RobertB's comment.
  Just call `searchRange` twice and you will clearly see why.
- `root`, `k1` and `k2` are all bad names.
  Rename them to better ones.
  E.G. `node`, `minimum` and `maximum`, respectively.
- You should use `k1 <= root.val <= k2` instead of `root.val >= k1 and root.val <= k2`.
- There is currently no need to `return []`. `return None` or any `return` work as well.
- If you wrap `searchRange` in another function, it can be much simpler.

If I were to do most of the above. (I didn't put it in a class.)

```
def search_range(root, minimum, maximum):
    nodes = []

    def recursive_search(node):
        if node is None:
            return None

        if node.val > minimum:
            recursive_search(node.left)
        if minimum <= node.val <= maximum:
            nodes.append(node.val)
        if node.val < maximum:
            recursive_search(node.right)

    recursive_search(root)
    return nodes
```